# Calling javascript method as callback in input oninput

Tags: javascript, html, callback

```js
class ClassWien {
  constructor(t, w) {
    this.t = t;
    this.w = w;
  }

  read_t() {
    let t = document.getElementById("wien_t").value;
    this.t = parseFloat(t);
    console.log(this);
  }

  read_w() {
    let w = document.getElementById("wien_w").value;
    this.w = parseFloat(w);
    console.log(this);
  }

  calculate() {
    this.w = 2.9e-3 / this.t;
    document.getElementById("wien_w").value = this.w;
    console.log(this);
  }
}

let wien = new ClassWien(0, 0);
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("wien_t").addEventListener("input", wien.read_t);
  document.getElementById("wien_w").addEventListener("input", wien.read_w);
  document.getElementById("wien_solve").addEventListener("click", wien.calculate);
}
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
body
{
    font: 100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #123c69;
    text-align: left;
    color: #000;
}

/* Define page layout */
.container
{
  width: 800px;
  background: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: none;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.indented
{
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0;
}

.indent-left
{
    padding: 15px 0 15px 180px;
    margin: 0;
}

h1, h4
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

h2
{
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

p, h4
{
    padding: 15px 0 0 15px;
    margin: 0;
}

ol
{
    padding-left: 45px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

  <title>Astronomy Equations</title>

  <script src=calculations.js></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form name="wien" class="indented">
      <h2>Wien's Law</h2>

      <p>This equation describes the relationship between the
         <b>temperature</b> of an object emitting a thermal spectrum and the
         <b>wavelength</b> of the brightest part of the emitted spectrum.</p>

      <table align="center" class="indent-left">
        <tbody>

          <tr>
            <td>temperature:</td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="wien_t" id="wien_t"></td>
            <td>Kelvins</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>wavelength:</td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="wien_w" id="wien_w"></td>
            <td>meters</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Solve" id="wien_solve"></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Clear"></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm writing a webpage that will solve an equation when the user enters all but one of the input values for a given equation. I've created a javascript class with methods for reading the numerical values from the html input fields and then solving for the missing value.

I can use a standalone function as the callback, such as:

```
<input oninput="read_t()">
```

But when I try to call the same function defined as a class method, such as:

```
<input oninput="equation.read_t()">
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: equation.read_t is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.oninput
```

I have created an instance of the class called "equation". So I'm not sure if I'm calling the method incorrectly within the input tag or this kind of thing simply isn't allowed in html/javascript.

I'm not sure I need to include the callback as part of the class or just make it a standalone function: that was working. It just seems cleaner to include the callback within the class. I'd like to know if instance methods can be callbacks or if I've made some other mistake.

Any help is appreciated!

*Update*: I have added a trimmed-down version of the page for inspection. I'm not sure what I changed in the last few hours of work, but the instance methods now execute when text is entered into the input fields. However, I have discovered that the input text is not assigned to the properties of instance `wien` as intended. This puzzled me for a while since assignment should be a pretty basic operation. Then I accidentally discovered that `this` in the `read_t` and `read_w` and `calculate` methods are referring to the input elements `wien_t`, `wien_w`, and `wien_solve`, not to the `wien` class instance. I guess I don't understand how `this` behaves in this case. I would have expected these instance methods would refer to the instance itself -- since they are defined as methods in ClassWien -- and not to the DOM elements they've been added to as EventListeners.

Comment: All else being equal, that should work fine. You need to provide an [mcve]. Use the live demo feature of the question editor.

Comment: FWIW, using `onxyz` attributes for event handling isn't best practice, not least because whatever function you call or variable you refer to in the handler text must be a global. So in your first example, `read_t` must be a global function. In your second, `equation` must be a global variable. The global namespace is really crowded; adding to it is best avoided. Use `addEventListener` and similar instead.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Quentin and T.J. I'm a beginner with javascript/html programming and with stack overflow, so the advice is appreciated.

I naively assumed an `onxyz` attribute in an input tag was `addEventListener` by other means. Is that strictly true? Is the "best practice" to separate html layout and javascript programming as much as possible by setting the callback in the JS file?

Answer (score -1):

maybe you need to call it using objectName.functionName() not className.functionName()

for instance

below format gave me the same error equation.read is not a function

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" oninput="equation.read()">
```

but below format works fine

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" oninput="equationObject.read()">
```

this is the code I wrote in my script tag

```
class equation{
    read(){
        var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
        console.log(x);
    }

}

equationObject = new equation();
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried replicating your problem and it seems that using static will enable you to call the function in the class and not using it will lead to the error you are experiencing.

Html

```
<input type="text" oninput="equation.read_t()"/>
```

Javascript

```
class equation {
    constructor() {

    }
    static read_t() {
        console.log("Hello");
    }
}
```

Static methods let you call methods on the class itself.

Answer (score -2):

Event handling using method bindings is typically better practice than `oninput`.

See the Mozilla Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener

Here's a quick summary:

1. Set id attribute.
2. Initialize equation class.
3. Bind method to input event.

Comment: While using `addEventListener` is usually better, it doesn't explain why `equation.read_t` is not a function here.